# No response after interview request

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, email, follow-up

I submitted a job application (FYI, very large company) and 5 days later, I received a phone interview request via email from the recruiter. I responded within an hour, telling the recruiter my available time, which was basically any day anytime. But it's been six days and I got no reply at all.  The recruiter told me that it was going to be an interview conducted by him and he was asking available time for this week (it's already Wednesday now) so I am starting to think that recruiter is super busy and still trying to figure out the schedule, which I hope, or he just simply forgot. Should I send him a follow-up email to kindly ask him again about the interview or should I just wait? I never had this experience before regarding the interview so I am sort of panicking.

p.s) for anyone who might see this thread, I sent an email to the recruiter that I am also available for the week after, and after about one week, a recruiter approached me again for a phone interview, which I was able to do it this time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I am in this same situation. I was approached by a company asking to give them some times/dates to set up a call for next week...I gave some pretty broad times on days. However, I haven't heard back and this thread was helpful in determining how and when I should reach out again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should I send him a follow-up email to kindly ask him again about the
> interview or should I just wait?

If you are expecting an interview this week, and by Wednesday haven't yet received any confirmation, then call the recruiter now. Ask when you should expect the interview to occur.

Leave a message if you don't get through to the recruiter, and follow up with an email.

Phone first. Always. Then email.

Answer (score 2):

Schedules and things are pretty chaotic right now. Some positions or companies are changing their hiring freeze decisions by the day, so its possible that there may be a pause on the position.

During the coronavirus pandemic you should be following up with companies to stay top of mind. You may be hesitant to do so because you don't want to come off as insensitive or desperate. However, following up shows that you are passionate and are highly interested in the role and the company. While your competition freezes, unsure what to do next, you should continue showing interest in the company in a respectful way to increase your chances of landing the job.

**When to Follow Up**

• If they tell you a date when they will get back to you, follow up the day after that date

• If they say let’s talk in “a few weeks” or “a couple of weeks,” follow up in 2 weeks

• If they give you no time frame follow up every 5 to 8 business days

**The Approach**

The strategy is to follow up in a way that does not require a response if they are not ready to email back. This shows a level of understanding and confidence that will leave the best impression on the company.

**First Follow Up Email:**

> Hi [Name],
>
> Given the uncertainty of everything going on I completely
> understand any delays or hesitations your team may have
> during the interview process.
>
> I am wishing you and your families health and wellness
> during this time.
>
> Do let me know if you need anything else additional from  me as you determine next steps. I continue to be enthusiastic about potentially joining your team.
>
> All the best,
> [Name]

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same thing happen to me, but I suspect the call was bogus, because at the end of the call he mentioned a consultancy he wanted me to be referred to if I didn't get a job with them.  I suspect this was his side hustle, forwarding on resumes to agencies for referral fees